get the list of the uri or address of android studio dependencies
I have been installing android studio on several machines and each time I have to re-download everything android studio needs for each
machine straight from the internet. How can i download all dependencies which android studio needs centrally and copy the files to each
machine to be used by android studio.
I was able to download gradle-bin.zip and modify the uri of android studio to look for the file locally but I could not do it for other item
The only items which were downloaded once were android studio itself, the system image and gradle-bin.zip files. all other items downloaded multiple times per system
I even tried to download emulator and unzip it to the emulator folder in android-sdk-folder but it was constantly downloading a new one everytime
I have gone through the following but did not find anything useful
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_execution_options
Android Studio: Configure offline build dependencies
https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#offline
https://developer.android.com/studio#offline
How to add dependency to Android Studio manually

Please where can i get the list of uri whic android studio would download items from?
how can i change that uri manually to download from my local system?

Please this is for both installation and creating a new project. Each project created android studio downloads a new gradle dependencies
